# Moderator diamond missing in User Reputation Leagues

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators, display-names, reputation-leagues

While browsing the [User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/quarter/superuser/2017-04-01/337631?sort=reputationchange#337631) for Super User, I noticed that DavidPostill's moderator diamond ♦︎ was not being displayed next to his username.

[image: User Rep League - No Mod Diamond]

**Shouldn't the usernames for Stack Exchange employees and moderators include the diamond?**

Comment: All are equal before the <s>law</s> reputation leagues!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not be displayed.

Here is another example

Martijn is an SO mod. But the mod diamond is not there.

Also check the Freehand in the URL.

It is StackExchance.com not a particular site. In StackExchange, they are not a moderator.

[image]

So, Their mod diamond should be visible only to the particular site and from other sites, only to the linked account section.

[image]